# VHDL Counter 0 to 99

Tags: vhdl, counter

i have a problem with my code it supposed to count from 0 to 99 but the problem that i have is that the counter starts at "80" and the Left number only increments at 10 seconds so it repeats..

Something like this
Starts at: 80 81 82 83 84 04 05 06 07 08 09

My code is this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned;
-- pin 86 selector de display 1 
-- pin 87 selec2 display
-- Seg A pin 85, Seg B 84, Seg C 83, D 82, E 81, F 78, Seg g pin 77, H 76
entity ContadorExamen is 
    port(
        CLK : in std_logic; -- se le asigna el pin   12
        --clk1hz : out std_logic ;-- se le asigna el pin 51
        datos : out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
        unidades : out std_logic;
        decenas: out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture BH_Examen2Parcial of ContadorExamen is
    signal freq1 : integer range 0 to 5000 := 0;
    signal freqDec : integer range 0 to 24999999 := 0;
    signal freq100 : integer range 0 to 249999999 := 0;
    signal tmp1 : std_logic := '0'; 
    signal tmp100 : std_logic := '0';
    signal tmpDec : std_logic := '0';
    signal counterUnidades : integer range 0 to 10 := 0;
    signal counterDecenas : integer range 0 to 10 := 0;
    signal segDecenas : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    signal segUnidades : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
begin
    process(CLK) is 
    begin 
        if(CLK'event and CLK = '1') then 
            if(freq1 >= 5000) then 
                freq1 <= 0;
                tmp1 <= not tmp1;
            else
                freq1 <= freq1 + 1;
                tmp1 <= tmp1;
            end if;

            if(freq100 >= 249999999) then 
                freq100 <= 0;
                tmp100 <= not tmp100;
            else
                freq100 <= freq100 + 1;
                tmp100 <= tmp100;
            end if;

            if(freqDec >= 24999999) then 
                freqDec <= 0;
                tmpDec <= not tmpDec;
            else
                freqDec <= freqDec + 1;
                tmpDec <= tmpDec;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

-- principio de cambios en el programa

    process(tmp1) is 
    begin 
        if(tmp1 = '1') then 
            unidades <= '0';
            decenas <= '1';
            datos <= segDecenas; 
        else
            datos <= SegUnidades;
            decenas <= '0';
            unidades <= '1';
        end if;
    end process;

    ParaContarUnidades:process(tmp100) is
    begin
        if (tmp100 = '1') then
            if(counterUnidades = 0) then 
                segUnidades <= "0000001";
            elsif (counterUnidades = 1 ) then 
                segUnidades <= "1001111";  
            elsif (counterUnidades = 2 ) then 
                segUnidades <= "0010010";
            elsif (counterUnidades = 3 ) then 
                segUnidades <= "0000110";
            elsif (counterUnidades = 4 ) then 
                segUnidades <= "1001100";
            elsif (counterUnidades = 5 ) then 
                segUnidades <= "0100100";
            elsif (counterUnidades = 6 ) then 
                segUnidades <= "1100000";
            elsif (counterUnidades = 7 ) then 
                segUnidades <= "0001111";
            elsif (counterUnidades = 8 ) then 
                segUnidades <= "0000000";
            elsif (counterUnidades = 9) then 
                segUnidades <= "0001100";
            else 
                segUnidades <= "1111111";
            end if; 
            if(counterUnidades < 9) then
                counterUnidades <= counterUnidades + 1;
            else 
                counterUnidades <= 0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    ParaContarDecenas:process(tmpDec) is
    begin
        if (tmpDec = '1') then
            if(counterDecenas = 0) then 
                segDecenas <= "0000001";
            elsif (counterDecenas = 1 ) then 
                segDecenas <= "1001111";  
            elsif (counterDecenas = 2 ) then 
                segDecenas <= "0010010";
            elsif (counterDecenas = 3 ) then 
                segDecenas <= "0000110";
            elsif (counterDecenas = 4 ) then 
                segDecenas <= "1001100";
            elsif (counterDecenas = 5 ) then 
                segDecenas <= "0100100";
            elsif (counterDecenas = 6 ) then 
                segDecenas <= "1100000";
            elsif (counterDecenas = 7 ) then 
                segDecenas <= "0001111";
            elsif (counterDecenas = 8 ) then 
                segDecenas <= "0000000";
            elsif (counterDecenas = 9) then 
                segDecenas <= "0001100";
            else 
                segDecenas <= "1111111";
            end if;
            if(counterDecenas < 9) then
                counterDecenas <= counterDecenas + 1;
            else 
                counterDecenas <= 0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Did it work in simulation? If not, which signals did what you expect and which did not?

Comment: The code works but i think its something wrong in the frequency management because the change of the numbers isn't correct

Comment: so look at the pulses out of the freq management. Are they at the right frequency? Are they the right length?

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues that you will want to look into:

Note that `counterDecenas` and `counterUnidades` should be in the sensitivity list of the processes that use them because (as written) you want your `segUnidades` and `segDecenas` signals to update when `tmpDec` or `tmp100` remain `'1'` but the counters change.

Moreover, you assign the counters to values based on themselves (such as `counterDecenas <= counterDecenas + 1;`) outside of a clocked process - this will produce a combinatorial loop. These need to be triggered only on clock edges.

Beyond that, it isn't clear what this entity is supposed to do. You say it is supposed to count from 0 to 99, but this clearly does more than the 1-liner that it would take to implement what you've described the desired functionality to be.

Comment: I believe the intent is to increment the counters on the rising edge of those signals, so in other words they *can't* increment while `tmpDec` or `tmp100` remain `'1'`, or at least that's what it looks like to me. A better solution might be to rethink the counting logic, use a single clock, and cascade the counters instead of triggering them independently.